# similarity members in ONE Collection or ONE array

Tags: collections, similarity, members

*Hi*
I have a textBox that get integer from user.
I want a button programming that for example if i give the textBox these numbers (5 8  16  16  5  1  0  5) with button_Click show "There is three 5 and
two 16".

I am using **WPF(C#)**. 
Thanks for your responses.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

public List refrence;

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        refrence = new List<int>();
    }


    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        refrence.Add(int.Parse(textBox.Text));
        textBox.Clear();
        listBox.Items.Clear();
    }
    private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> q = new List<int>();
        int[] query = refrence.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < query.Length; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < query.Length; j++)
            {
                if (query[i] == query[j])
                {
                    q.Add(query[j]);
                    var qwe = q.Distinct();
                    foreach(var item in qwe)
                    listBox.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
    }</i>
```

But it shows 
5
5
5
16
5
16 in listBox